# AngularJS : how to evaluate dynamically created expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to evaluate dynamically created expressions. For now, my code is :

```
var new_row = '<tr><td><select><option ng-repeat="service in services" value="{{service.id}}">{{service.nom}}</option></select></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>';
var table = $('#implication');
$(table.children().get(1)).append($.parseHTML(new_row));
```

The content of new_row is well added in the right place, but angular expressions in the added content aren't evaluated.

Is it possible to do that and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`$compile`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) service:

> Compiles a piece of HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a
>   template function, which can then be used to link scope and the
>   template together.